# Aligning a block with html div and style?

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to the fronted and I am experiencing some trouble to center a block in the footer of a Wordpress website.

Here is my code:

```
<div align="center style="display:flex;justify-content:center;flex-direction:column;">
```

Unfortunately the block still stays in the left of the footer.

Comment: Can you post more details please? Please read [mcve]

Comment: nb. you  have an error in your html  you missed a close quote after center.

Comment: You are missing `"` but you should think about using CSS rather than adding your styling to the html itself

Answer (score 2):

Just set the display to flex, and set align-items(for vertical alignment) and justify-items to center(for horizontal alignment)

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  hi </div>
```

Comment: still doesnt' works... probably my block is not placed in the mid of the upper class/object?

Answer (score 1):

A div element is a block element by default. Since it is not clear from your question whether you want to centre the div or the content, I will give the two possibilities.

1. Centre inline elements within a block container.
2. Centre block elements within a block container.

```css
.footer {  
  background: #999;
  padding: 20px;    
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.flexi {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footerBlock {
  background:green; 
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Center Inline within Block</h2>
<div class="footer center">
  <div>
    FOOTER Inline
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<h2>Center Block within Block</h2>
<div class=" flexi">
  <div class="footerBlock" >
    Footer Block
   </div
</div>
```

As you can see, it depends on your application. If you only want to insert a copyright line, the align element is sufficient. If you want to have a more complex footer with one container and within this container there should be other containers and then next to each other. You can implement this with CSS Flex or CSS Gridsystem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

your block left cause you must position flex items horizontally in the same direction as text

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:center;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with grid system

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">Column-Center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is bootstrap class... and if the OP doesn't use bootstrap?